# C# e Entity Framework com ForeignKey entre classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net

Galera nos meus projetos `.Net MVC` uso a estrutura abaixo. Meus projetos, são com `Entity Framework`.

A pasta `Entidades`, é as classes que eu utilizo no `DbContext`.

[image: Minha estrutura de projeto]

### Detalhando o problema

Tenho a classe `Cliente`,  que tem `ForeignKey` para a classe `Pessoa`.
Para não ter fazer `DbContext.Cliente.Include("Pessoa")`, criei o `PessoaDTO` que é uma classe com alguns campos da classe `Pessoa` e como `PessoaDTO` tem uma `Interface` consigo utilizar ela em outras classes como `Filial` e afins.

E desta forma, posso montar um `ViewPartial`, para mostrar os dados da pessoa de forma "genérica" e várias `Views`.

## Dúvidas

- Existe algo mais inteligente e performático para a estrutura acima?
- Se usar `DTOs` eles podem ter métodos?

## Exemplo de uso

```
public ActionResult Detalhar(int id)
{
    using (var db = new Conexao())
    {
        var registro = db.Cliente.Find(id);
        registro.DTO();

        return View(registro);
    }
}
```

## Fontes das classes

#### Classe Pessoa

```
public class Pessoa : IEntidadeBase, IFixo
{
    [Key]
    public int PessoaID { get; set; }

    [Obrigatorio]
    [Display(Name = "Tipo de Pessoa")]
    public int TipoPessoaID { get; set; }

    [Obrigatorio]
    [Display(Name = "Sexo")]
    public int SexoID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CPF/CNPJ")]
    public string CNPJCPF { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Identificação Interna / Matrícula")]
    public string IdentificacaoInterna { get; set; }

    [Obrigatorio]
    [Display(Name = "Nome/Nome Fantasia")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
```

#### Classe Cliente

```
public class Cliente : IEntidadeBase, IFixo, IPessoaDTO
{
    [Key]
    public int ClienteID { get; set; }

    public int PessoaID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PessoaID")]
    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public PessoaDTO PessoaDTO { get; set; }

    public void DTO()
    {
        if (Pessoa != null)
        {                
            PessoaDTO = new PessoaDTO();
            PessoaDTO.Popular(Pessoa);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Classe PessoaDTO

```
public class PessoaDTO 
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "CNPJ/CPF")]
    public string CNPJCPF { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Tipo de Pessoa")]
    public string TipoDePessoa { get; set; }
    public string Sexo { get; set; }

    public string Rotulo { get; set; }

    public void Popular(Pessoa registro)
    {
        Nome = registro.Nome;
        CNPJCPF = registro.CNPJCPF;

        TipoDePessoa = registro.TipoPessoaID == 1 ? "Física" : registro.TipoPessoaID == 2 ? "Juridica" : String.Empty;
        Sexo = registro.SexoID == 1 ? "Masculino" : registro.SexoID == 2 ? "Feminino" : "Não aplicável";            

        Rotulo = String.Format("{0} [{1}]", Nome, CNPJCPF);
    }
}
```

Comment: Não sei se é a intenção, mas você quer usar o DDD ou "Domínio"  é só o nome mesmo, porque se for considerar o DDD, você não poderia associar suas entidades com DTOs, manter dependência com infraestrutura, ter as anotações de [KEY] etc nas entidades, ou até mesmo acessar os dbcontext diretamente da controller já que você tem os repositories, mas se realmente isso fizer diferença para você, poderia criar DTOS, MODELS VIEW ou DYNAMICS e usar o micro ORM para fazer as querys personalizadas para a saída que desejar. Patterns nesse caso seria parcialmente o CQRS.

Answer (score 0):

**Utilize as seguintes Técnicas: Métodos de Extensão "Extensions Methods" e Reflexão "Reflection"**

Métodos de Extensão : irá te dar a liberdade de referenciar um projeto a ser compartilhado e Reflexão: poderá copiar as informações das propriedades dos objetos que contém os nomes e tipos comuns.

```
var registro = db.Cliente.Find(id);
         
var dto = registro.ConverterObjeto<Pessoa, PessoaDTO>();
        
return View(dto);

public static class TiposComplexos
{
    public static Destino ConverterObjeto<Origem, Destino>(this Origem origem)
    {
        var destino = Activator.CreateInstance<Destino>();

        foreach (var propriedadeOrigem in origem.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var propriedadeDestino = destino.GetType().GetProperty(propriedadeOrigem.Name);

            if (propriedadeDestino != null && propriedadeOrigem.Name == propriedadeDestino.Name)
                propriedadeDestino.SetValue(destino, propriedadeOrigem.GetValue(origem, null));
        }

        return destino;
    }
}
```

Comment: O [AutoMapper](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html) faz isso e acredito que de forma mais performática, pois é no Startup da aplicação, não?

Comment: Com certeza o automapper é um framework já testado, estável e homologado pela comunidade,  porém o exemplo que citei foi em caso de uma aplicações que não suportam versões do Automaper, como por exemplo um sistema legado, portanto temos que atender ao cenário, depois da uma analise no código do Automapper no github, ele é implementado utilizado o recurso "reflection" citado no exemplo. Ou também dependendo do cliente ele não aprove a utilização de framework em sua arquitetura "infelizmente no mundo real acontece isso", dai tem casos que deverá reinventar a roda.